# LEFT vs. DATE_FORMAT in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

LEFT or DATE_FORMAT, which is faster to re-format date in SELECT query in mysql?
I'll show an example of this problem.

**Info of PERSON table**

| Column name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| NAME | VARCHAR(20) |
| YEAR | DATETIME |

**PERSON**

| NAME | YEAR |
| --- | --- |
| Travis | 2020-01-01 |
| Sam | 2021-01-01 |

If execute '**SELECT** YEAR **FROM** PERSON' query, can see below result.

| YEAR |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00 |
| 2021-01-01 00:00:00 |

But I want result like below.

| YEAR |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01 |
| 2021-01-01 |

So, I wanted use one of below queries.

- **SELECT** **LEFT**(YEAR,10) **FROM** PERSON
- **SELECT** **DATE_FORMAT**(YEAR, '%Y-%m-%d')

However, I wonder what query perform better.
Please, help me..

Comment: Makes no difference. Besides, a DATE field will never return  00:00:00. You need to **make sure** it's DATE and not DATETIME instead of wasting your time with this question. "which is faster" asked out of the blue is not a "problem" one needs "help" with but a mere curiosity

Comment: I assume DATE(year) FROM person would be fastest, but no need to ask such questions. Just try out. I agree with @YourCommonSense that this "time component" with zeros only doesn't make sense.

Comment: @YourCommonSense
I'm totally newbie.. so thank you for yours answer!

Comment: @JonasMetzler I'm totally newbie.. so thank you for yours answer!

Comment: As a general rule try to keep date functions applying on dates and string functions applying on strings. Welcome to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, `LEFT()` is nearly four times faster, based on this test on my M1 Macbook. Your result might vary.

```
mysql> select benchmark(100000000, left(year, 10)) from person;
+--------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, left(year, 10)) |
+--------------------------------------+
|                                    0 |
+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (1.75 sec)

mysql> select benchmark(100000000, date_format(year, '%Y-%m-%d')) from person;
+-----------------------------------------------------+
| benchmark(100000000, date_format(year, '%Y-%m-%d')) |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   0 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (6.81 sec)
```

But given that I had to execute both expressions 100 million times to observe a significant difference, both of them are so fast that I wouldn't worry about it. It's likely that other parts of the query will be of far greater influence on performance.

Worrying about which of these two functions has better performance is like worrying if it's better to use one finger or two fingers to lift a 100kg barbell.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness :) 
It's a perfect metaphor for newbie like me!!

Comment: How about simply `DATE(year)`?